# Logcat displaying "permission denied" error when trying to debug application with ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am using a **Reliance 3G TAB** at my office. It has a `USB debugging` option but it doesn't let us debug the application. A message is displayed in `logcat` that says `permission denied`. How can I debug my application? Are there any other options?

Comment: Did you write a space in logcat or is that just a typo? Do other ADB commands work?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik which `adb` command are you talking about?

Comment: Any. Is it just logcat that throws this error?

Comment: Did you install a debuggable version of the application?  Are you trying to do java-level or native-level debugging?

Comment: yes i have installed debuggable application. i am doing java level debigging

Comment: @RichardBorcsik logcat shows this error only when i use this tab. other tab works fine.

Comment: And other adb commands like push/pull/shell work with this tab?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik haven't tried yet..but will tried soon..Recently i came to know that logs may be not showing as m using fedora(linux) ..so m also thinking to try out in Windows.